# What's the name of this caterpillar?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

It was found in the state of Virginia, on the east coast of the United States.

[image: Mystery caterpillar on a leaf.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be a species of Fritillary. Below is a picture of a Marsh Fritillary.

[image: Marsh fritillary]
<sup>Marsh fritillary. Source: [Butterfly Conservation.org](http://butterfly-conservation.org/files/marsh-fritillary-larva1_peter_eeels_web.jpg)</sup>

I do not think it is a woolly bear or giant leopard moth, just because the hairs seems too sparse for a woolly bear and it lacks the distinct red striping of the giant leopard moth caterpillar. It does not seem to be arctiinae to me.

Comment: Could you add a picture of you suggested species? Regardless, +1

Comment: http://butterfly-conservation.org/files/marsh-fritillary-larva1_peter_eeels_web.jpg Maybe a marsh fritillary.

Answer (score 0):

It's Woolly Bear Caterpillar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrharctia_isabella

Comment: Can you explain why you think so? This looks quite different then the larvae that show up in a standard Google search.

Comment: Its spikes are short so the closest match I can think of was Woolly Bear. But it can be Giant Leopard Moth Caterpillar.